# 70s movie where implants would make people peaceful

Tags: story-identification, movie

This is a movie I saw as a child, toward the end of the 70s.

It had a similar vibe to *Invasion of the Body Snatchers*.

The story is about some guy that invents some implant that looks like a small metal tube. If I remember correctly, it was inserted on the side of the head, by the temple. The recipients of the implants would become very civil and peaceful people. He becomes convinced that this was the way to be and soon more people have the implant. But then people with the implant start to force others to have the implant, etc.

The main guy is afflicted with some disease that makes him age quickly. At the end, the main characters are with him in a building and can see the plaza below where one of their non-implanted friend goes (to make some point I forget about) and the implant guys all converge to him to convert him.

The rest of the protagonists know that the only safe place is in the tower, with the guy that started everything and has now passed of old age due to his condition.

I don't remember the rest of the movie, but I would really like to find what it was.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not a movie but a 1978 French mini-series titled *Le Mutant*, although I guess it could have been edited into a movie for foreign broadcast.

I previously identified it for:

- [70's sci-fi dystopian mini-series: conspiracy to insert chips in brains to decrease violence](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/83805/)
- [70s TV miniseries: antagonist gets followers to his pacifist ideology through mind control devices](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/208553/)

[The forum I linked to](http://www.devildead.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=14211) (though the link is now dead) had these relevant recollections (translated):

> The story follows a reporter investigating people behaving weirdly. She meets an odd guy who will only eat tiny green cubes of an unknown food. **And he takes control of people by putting a weird thing in their necks.** At the end, he tells the journalist he enslaved the whole world through a TV recording, **because he died prematurely**, and she ends up being the only "normal" person, watching the mind-controlled people on the screens... [...]
>
> A fascinating, horrifying sci-fi series where an organization attempts to uncover who is Saül Masson, son of the rich Professor Masson. A strange blond teenager who only eats an equally strange green cube, **all while from the top of his tower, an old man (whom we will only see the scrawny hand of, laying on his armchair)** spends his time watching TV screens, seemingly monitoring everything...

All six episodes are on YouTube (in French, though); the sixth episode has the following "reveal" line at 48'58:

> **Professor Masson**: His cells were ageing ten times faster than anyone else's. And I couldn't do anything about it. Over time, the process sped up. Look at him. He's ten years old. He's only ten.

as well as the "implant guys converging to the main character" bit you remember, which is the very end of the series:

Comment: that was it, and I saw it in France! 35+ years of trying to find what it was! thanks a lot!

Comment: @Thomas you're welcome, enjoy the rewatch! :) (for further reference, you having seen that in France wuld have been helpful ot have in the question as well :) )