# 1980s movie or TV series about a sentient computer that controls people by implanting microchips in the backs of their heads

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv, artificial-intelligence

I remember seeing this movie, it could even have been a TV series, in the early 1980s but the movie, or TV series, was clearly older probably '70s.  It seemed to be European.  I can't remember the name.

The plot was about a computer that becomes sentient, and starts controlling humans by implanting a chip in the backs of their heads.  It aimed to control all of humanity.  Some people are aware of this and try to stop it.

Comment: https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0667957/?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardwired_(film)?

Comment: Is it set on Earth or elsewhere & how big is the cast? I have one in mind that only had a cast of 3 besides the robot that was chipping them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're slightly misremembering and it's not a sentient computer, but rather a mutant surrounded by computer monitors, then it can be *Le Mutant* (1978):

- the time period matches
- it's European (French, actually)
- it's a mini-series, which may have been compiled into a movie I guess
- people get control chips implanted into their necks

From [Wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Mutant), translated:

> The various nations of the world have decided to make peace and destroy their weapons, while society's control over all activities through video surveillance is increasing. A mysterious scientist leads this pacifist movement through these Peace Legions. But the apparition of a Mutant, endowed with powers that go beyond nature, will call everything into question.
>
> The series is entirely organized in flash-back.  An investigation is conducted on this Mutant, and each episode consists of examining the memories of a witness, using a memory sounder to display the memories on a screen.

All six episodes (50 minutes each) are on YouTube:

---

Remembered and adapted from my answers to:

- [70s movie where implants would make people peaceful](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/237897/)
- [70s TV miniseries: antagonist gets followers to his pacifist ideology through mind control devices](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/208553/)
- [70's sci-fi dystopian mini-series: conspiracy to insert chips in brains to decrease violence](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/83805/)

Comment: This was the tv series, I could not remember very well as I was rather young at the time, but this is it !!! I now have seen a couple of the episodes and it is exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks you very much !!!!!!

Comment: @maraven2001 you're welcome, enjoy the rewatch!